# Sum of (double) fetch request field

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Is it possible to get the sum of a core data (through a fetch request) field (double) in Swift UI? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could use the `reduce` method.

```
var sum: Double {
    fetchRequest.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.number }
}
```

This starts with an initial value of 0, and for each item in the FetchRequest, it adds the `number` property to the accumulated total.

Assuming you have an entity called `SomeEntity` in your .xcdatamodeld file, with an attribute called `number`, the whole code might look like

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: SomeEntity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \SomeEntity.number, ascending: false)]) var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<SomeEntity>

    var sum: Double {
        fetchRequest.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.number }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Button("Add number") {
                    let entity = SomeEntity(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                    entity = Double.random(in: 0...10)
                    try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("Sum")) {
                Text("\(sum)")
            }

            Section {
                ForEach(fetchRequest, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0.number)")
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for this! Couldn't find an answer anywhere.