# How to sum filtered Core Data in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

**How to sum filtered Core Data values (using predicate) in SwiftUI app?**

I have 1 entity named **NPTransaction**. It has 5 attributes and I would like to sum values from the attribute named **value (Integer 64)**. Basically, it would sum up values of income in selected month (right now it's set to current Date() in the example code, but later on it will be set to whole current month).

I have found similar question regarding Swift, but I cannot make this code to work in my app.
Link to related question: [How to sum the numbers(Int16) of stored core data - Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382971/how-to-sum-the-numbersint16-of-stored-core-data-swift-3)

Based on code from the link, I have following code right now:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DashboardView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var selectedDate = Date()

   // This code in private var below produces many errors like:
   // Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'
   // Use of undeclared type 'NSEntityDescription'
   // Use of undeclared type 'NSFetchRequest'
   // - so I assume that this linked question may be outdated or I should take different approach using SwiftUI
    private var income: Int64 {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let entityDesc: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "NPTransaction", in: context)!
        let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entityDesc

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", selectedDate)
        let records = try! context.fetch(request)

        try! context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
        let monthlyIncome = result.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value(forKey: "value") as? Int64 ?? 0) }
        return monthlyIncome
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {                    
               Text("Monthly income:")
               Text("\(income) USD")
                }

// more code...
```

I am just learning Swift and SwiftUI, so maybe there is a better and completely different way of solving this problem?

Comment: NSExpressionDescription can be useful.  for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099914/swift-4-coredata-nsfetchrequest-sum-over-computed-variable

Comment: Bear in mind that Date() includes time, so it is very unlikely that your predicate matches any objects.  I would start by removing the predicate, to get working code to calculate the sum of ALL values.  Then add the predicate back in later - to get “today’s total”, you will need the predicate equivalent of “date > midnight last night AND date < midnight tonight”.  Likewise, to calculate a monthly total you will need to work out the start of the month and end of the month, and fetch all records in between.

Comment: Thanks, pbasdf, good point. I have solved this date predicate, though. I would also welcome a solution just for date > Date(). The problem I still cannot solve is how to sum the data.

Comment: Gagan_iOS, thanks, but question from your link is not answered. I don’t know how to use NSExpressionDescription properly and cannot find working SwiftUI examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found similar problem in this question:
[Sum of (double) fetch request field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956207/sum-of-double-fetch-request-field)
I have modified the code a little and came up with this solution:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct DashboardView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    // FetchRequest with predicate set to "after now" 
    @FetchRequest(entity: NPTransaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NPTransaction.value, ascending: false)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", Date() as NSDate)) var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<NPTransaction>

    // sum results using reduce
    var sum: Int64 {
        fetchRequest.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("sum")
                        Text("\(sum)")
                            .font(.largeTitle)

                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()

                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
    }

}

struct DashboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return DashboardView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your current code, you're trying to reduce non existent variable called `result` which I believe you got from the code you linked.  You're also making two fetches which shouldn't be necessary.  Hopefully this helps.

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", selectedDate)
let records = try! context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

let monthlyIncome = records.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value(forKey: "value") as? Int64 ?? 0) }
return monthlyIncome
```

Also, you can sum values from CoreData via an NSFetchRequest and NSExpression.  Here's an example I found in this article: [Group by, Count and Sum in CoreData](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/04/group-by-count-and-sum-in-coredata/).

```
let keypathExp1 = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "value")
let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [keypathExp1])
let sumDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
sumDesc.expression = expression
sumDesc.name = "sum"
sumDesc.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType

let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "NPTransaction")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.propertiesToFetch = [sumDesc]
request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

let monthlyIncome = try! context.fetch(request) as? Int64 

if let monthlyIncome = monthlyIncome {
    print("monthly income total: \(monthlyIncome)")
}
```

Edit: I amended the sample code with your entity and column name.

Comment: Thanks, clawesome, but I am still getting many errors. Using your first code I am getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'request'`. Or `Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'` or `Use of undeclared type 'NSFetchRequest'`. When using second code, I am getting things like `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSExpressionDescription'` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFetchRequest'`. I think I am mixing too much code here. And is this example from your link to be used with SwiftUI? Maybe I am putting this code in wrong part of files?

Comment: Like for example on line `let sumDesc = NSExpressionDescription()` I am getting an error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSExpressionDescription'`. I don't know what to do with this :/

Comment: OK, I have fixed few errors simply adding `import CoreData` at the beginning of the file. But still on line `let monthlyIncome = try! context.fetch(request) as? Int64` I am getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'context'`. And if I try to add code `let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`, I am getting error: `Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'`. Even when I have a line `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext` at the beginning of my view struct (which worked for my other code using core data).

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the code references you had(`let context` for example) to already be working.  If you're getting `Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'` then you most likely your app delegate is renamed something other than `AppDelegate` or it does not have a `managedObjectContext` variable which might be because of using SwiftUI.  Looks like you already solve the issue though.

Comment: Thanks, clawesome. AppDelegate has this name. I don't know what was the problem. I solved this in another way. I don't know if correct very much, but it works. Thanks a lot that for trying to help me. All the best!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.  Sometimes the best solution is the one that works.