# Sum attribute from filtered SwiftUI CoreData list

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, sum, swiftui

I want to sum the attribute amount from my entities and show it but only from the todays inputted data

Here's my entities [ExpenseLog Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9gC6.png)

And here's my fetch request to get todays data

```
 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
 var context: NSManagedObjectContext

 @FetchRequest(
    entity: ExpenseLog.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ExpenseLog.date, ascending: false)
    ]
    ,predicate: NSPredicate(format: "(date => %@) AND (date <= %@)", DateHelper.startOfDay(day: NSDate()), DateHelper.endOfDay(day: NSDate()))
)
private var result: FetchedResults<ExpenseLog>
```

Please help me how to do it, thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum filtered Core Data in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681508/how-to-sum-filtered-core-data-in-swiftui)

Comment: Because my attribute use decimal data type: Cannot convert value of type 'NSDecimalNumber?' to expected argument type 'Decimal' and it always keep ask me to Insert ' as! Decimal' after i already put as! Decimal. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can add variable to sum the result of the fetch like this:

```
private var sum: Decimal {
    result.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount.decimalValue }
}
```