# Show the highest Number from an Attribute in an Entity from CoreData / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, attributes, entity

I have an Entity and in this Entity I have a few Attributes. For Example: "Days".
And I have a Label, and I want to show there the highest number that are saved in "Days".
For example an user archived 10, 8, 11, .. days.
(In the Label should be 11. All numbers are saved as new Entity in "Days".)
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to get the max value directly from Core Data or fetch all objects and get the max value from the array? Either way this is a duplicate so you should be able to find an answer with some research.

Comment: This is my array. @State var cards:[NSManagedObject] = []

Comment: And in this array is all saved. And I want to get the highest Number from the Attribute "Days". So how can I do this? @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your entity is Cards and days is an attribute then you can use below approach:
Get the context and then fetch the all objects of an entity and then we can pick the days and find the maximum.

```
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        context = delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let context = context else{
            return
        }
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "Cards")

        do {
            let cards = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let maximumValue = cards.map{$0.days}.max()
          }
          catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sort descriptor in your fetch request.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "days", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
do {
   result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch {
                
}
```

The first element in the fetch result will contain the highest number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SwiftUI-centric approach to try, using @FetchRequest (as the question refers to SwiftUI with Core Data).

```
// Assuming Entity is named "Card" and attribute is "days"

struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

  @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [], predicate: nil, animation: nil)
  private var cards: FetchedResults<Card>

  var maxValue: Int {
      let daysArray = cards.compactMap{$0.days} as [Int]
      return daysArray.max() ?? 0
  }

  var body: some View {
      Text("Highest Days: \(maxValue)")
  }
}
```

The above fetches all Cards, then uses the computed property maxValue to find the max value for days.

Alternatively, you could allow Core Data to sort the results as it fetches them, and then you can rely on the first result containing the max value:

```
  @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Card.days, ascending: false)], predicate: nil, animation: nil)
  private var cards: FetchedResults<Card>

  var maxValue: Int {
      return cards.first?.days ?? 0
  }
```

(FWIW, this post helped me down the path to solve a need similar to yours: [how-to-sum-filtered-core-data-in-swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681508/how-to-sum-filtered-core-data-in-swiftui) )